# Getting updates inside a function (Telegram bot, Python3, python-telegram-bot library)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a telegram bot with https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot library in python3.

I want to make a message sender bot. This is my code now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""#==============================# Imports #==============================#"""
import logging, time, telegram
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from datetime import datetime

"""#==============================# Enable logging #==============================#"""
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.WARN)#DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

"""#==============================# Log error #==============================#"""

def error(update, context):
    #Log Errors caused by Updates.
    logger.warning("Update '%s' caused error '%s'", update, context.error)


"""#==============================# Bot commands #==============================#"""

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Bot joined the conversation!")

def get_additional_updates(update, message):
***My Problem***


"""#==============================# MAIN #==============================#"""

def main():
    updater = Updater("<TOKEN>", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start)
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("send", get_additional_updates)

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't know what should I do to get the updates inside the 'get_additional_updates' function.
What I want to do, is: I type /send, after this the bot waits for my message, I type my message in and send it. The problem is, that I can't figure it out how to get the second message (the message itself) to the 'get_additional_updates' function.

I can't find it in the documentation, and I'm very new to programming as well.

Please help me with the code I need to type there in order to get the additional messages.
Let me know if you can't understand what is my question, I'll try to explain better.

Thanks a lot!

P.S.:Sorry, if my english is bad, I'm trying to upgrade that as well.

Comment: hi, could you solve this problem? If yes How?

Answer (score 1):

You should use conversation bot ,Check the example [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py)